# Android accessibility: Read hidden text after click of button

Tags: android, kotlin, button, accessibility, focus

So I have a requirement around accessibility wherein a button needs to be read out when it comes in focus and then another text to be read out after user clicks on it.

For example,
An "OK" button when focussed should read "OK" but when a user taps on it, it should read out some other text eg. "Navigating to the other page".

Is there a way in Android to implement this?

I have not been able to find anything around it.

Comment: Based on other questions I’m suspicious when somebody tries to change what screen readers announce. You could consider it code smell. Would you mind sharing more of why you’d like to announce additional text? At least in HTML, you manage user’s expectations with `role`. You don’t need to add that a `link` will navigate somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`View#announceForAccessibility(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#announceForAccessibility(java.lang.CharSequence)) to make a general announcement - so in your `OnClickListener` get a reference to some `View` (e.g. your `Button`, it doesn't matter what it is) and call that on it.

Like it says in the docs, this is a convenience function that creates a very general "something is getting announced for no specific reason" event - you might want to give more context, like creating a [`TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent#TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) event. This might be more helpful to the user (depending on how the accessibility service handles it) and could provide a better experience, since stuff that's read out is prioritised depending on what it is. I don't have time to get into it here, but it's something you can investigate if you want

---

Also I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but just in case - if the user focuses your button, it should say *"[OK] button, double tap to [some description]"*. The bits in brackets you can customise, the rest is standard description for a `Button` in the UI. **You shouldn't change this to just say "OK".**

That predictable and consistent system is there for a reason, to help partially sighted and blind people understand exactly what's going on with the app they're using. It might sound clunky at times, but it's meant to be functional, not slick. So we shouldn't try to get around it and make it "sound better" by removing important info and context that some people really need. I don't know if that's what you meant, but it's always worth mentioning!